# Why is the cshtml showing links for users not in my role?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, owin

Why is the cshtml showing links for users not in my role?

To be clear non admin users should not be seeing the reset password and the create user links.  In my case they are seeing the links.

In my layout.cshtml I have the following code:

```
        @if (HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        { 
            @Html.ActionLink("My Wonderful App", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
            <span class="navbar-right">
                if (HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("Administrators"))
                {
                   @Html.ActionLink("Reset Password", "ResetPassword", "Auth", null, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
                   @Html.ActionLink("Create User", "CreateAccount", "Auth", null, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
                }
                @Html.ActionLink("Logoff", "Logoff", "Auth", null, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
            </span>
        }
```

In my controller when the user logs in I have:

```
// For clarity assume:
// userName = "myTest@tester.com"
// IsAdmin = false

var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(new[] {
                                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, userName),
                                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, userName)                                
                            }, "ApplicationCookie");

                        if (IsAdmin)
                        {
                            identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Administrators"));
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "User"));
                        }

                        var ctx = Request.GetOwinContext();
                        var authManager = ctx.Authentication;

                        authManager.SignIn(identity);
```

The controllers are working correctly by denying access when the users click the link.

```
[Authorize(Roles="Administrators")]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be a razor syntax issue.

```
@if (HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    { 
        @Html.ActionLink("My Wonderful App", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
        <span class="navbar-right">
            if (HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("Administrators"))
            {
               @Html.ActionLink("Reset Password", "ResetPassword", "Auth", null, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
               @Html.ActionLink("Create User", "CreateAccount", "Auth", null, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
            }
            @Html.ActionLink("Logoff", "Logoff", "Auth", null, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
        </span>
    }
```

Should have been:

```
@if (HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{ 
    @Html.ActionLink("My Wonderful App", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
    <span class="navbar-right">
        @if (HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("Administrators"))
        {
           @Html.ActionLink("Reset Password", "ResetPassword", "Auth", null, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
           @Html.ActionLink("Create User", "CreateAccount", "Auth", null, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
        }
        @Html.ActionLink("Logoff", "Logoff", "Auth", null, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
    </span>
}
```